# Date input and toLocaleDateString using different locales

Tags: javascript, date

I reside in Canada, where we format our dates dd/mm/yyyy. I'm seeing something unusual when I'm calling `toLocaleDateString()`

HTML:

```
<input type="date" value="2016-01-13">
<p id="container">
</p>
```

JS:

```
var d = new Date("2016-01-13");
document.getElementById('container').innerText = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

The value of the date input is what I would expect - `2016-01-13`.

The value of the paragraph is the American format - `12-01-2016` (the change in day is due to localizing from GMT to EST)

Chrome language is set to Canadian, as is my system setting (Windows 7). The date input seems to be respecting that, but I thought `toLocaleDateString()` would pick up Canada as my locale and format the date appropriately.

MSDN describes this function like this:

> dateObj.toLocaleDateString( [locales][, options])
>
> locales (Optional). An array of locale strings that contain one or more language or locale tags. If you include more than one locale string, list them in descending order of priority so that the first entry is the preferred locale. If you omit this parameter, the default locale of the JavaScript runtime is used.

Is the JavaScript runtime default locale something the user can change? I'm guessing not given my lack of success.

The different formatting between the date input and `toLocaleDateString` is quite baffling to me, any thoughts on how I can align the two?

http://jsfiddle.net/DfkU5/283/

Comment: You should not expect anything, since [*toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring) is **entirely** implementation dependent. Also, a convenient format for the OP should not be based on where they are but on what they want to see (i.e. preferences are not necessarily dependent on locale, hence *toLocaleString* is somewhat of a misnomer). Would a US person travelling to England expect all their devices to start reporting dates in d/m/y format? Or would they rather set a preference to see m/d/y always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the JavaScript runtime default locale something the user can change?

That depends entirely on the browser developers, they can do whatever they like. However, they *tend* to use system settings, but not always. Chrome ignores my settings for *toLocalString*, showing dates in m/d/y format when my preference is for d/m/y.

Safari, Chrome and Firefox all show a different string for *toLocaleDate*, which makes it just about useless.

> The different formatting between the date input and toLocaleDateString is quite baffling to me, any thoughts on how I can align the two?

By far the best solution is to present dates in an unambiguous format, the easiest being to use the month name. All the following are unambiguous and easy to read:

```
19-Mar-2016
March 19, 2016
19 March, 2016
```

To do that you can write your own formatter (maybe 10 lines of code), or perhaps use a library.

In regard to input type date, not all browsers support it and there are [*lots of issues*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20support%20for%20input%20type%20date), so if you're going to use it you must check for support (fairly trivial) and if lacking, provide a fallback that does something sensible. And once you have a good fallback, you might as well implement it everywhere and forget input type date.

Then all the issues associated with it are gone. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Pass your locale as an arugment to `toLocaleDateString()`
e.g:

```
date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')
```

or if you want to specify some fallback language, do this

```
date.toLocaleDateString(['en-CA','en-US'])
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what I don't want to do. Determining a user's locale can be error prone, I'd just like some consistency.

Comment: @MisterEpic type    navigator.language in your browser console to see whats the runtime locale. It shouldn't be in "en-US" otherwise javascript is right in displaying the date in american format.

Comment: That will only work if the host supports the [*Intl*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) object and the script knows an appropriate setting to pass. Navigator language setting doesn't necessarily have any bearing on preferences for date formatting.